# create.js, createPHP and Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

We are trying to implement in page editing for our cake app. We would like to use create.js for the frontend and createphp to handle the connection between create.js and cakephp. I have been doing a lot of research on RDFa and I am generally baffled by how all this links together.

What I have:

1. Editable interface
2. Endpoints via actions in cakephp

What I need:

1. A way to convert the data sent by create.js to my database structure and a way to send data to create.js for rendering.

I have gotten to the point in createphp where you are supposed to create your own mapper. I don't know what the mapper should contain. It mentions that is has built-in mappers (Midgard\CreatePHP\Mapper ?) but I don't know how to load those either.

I have read the documentation but it doesn't give details on how to accomplish these tasks.

Thank you for your help on the two following questions.

**1. How can I convert my data from create.js to cake and then back again for the views? (possible solution createPHP but doesn't have to be)**

**2. How do I create a mapper for createPHP or where could I find information to learn how to create a mapper for my instance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, the documentation is unfortunately rather sparse. I will create an issue on createphp linking to this post, to give some hints how the documentation could be improved.

I try to explain how things work:

To convert the data from the REST call to your model, you indeed need a RdfMapper instance. See the [setup section of the tutorial](https://github.com/flack/createphp/blob/master/documentation/tutorial.md#setup) how you bootstrap that. the bundle comes with mappers for [doctrine](https://github.com/flack/createphp/blob/master/src/Midgard/CreatePHP/Mapper/DoctrineOrmMapper.php), which you can read for inspiration if you do not use doctrine. I recommend to extend [AbstractRdfMapper](https://github.com/flack/createphp/blob/master/src/Midgard/CreatePHP/Mapper/AbstractRdfMapper.php) in that case.

To render the rdfa, you need to configure what fields of your class should be what rdf type. You can either use the array mapper as in the tutorial, or use the xml mapping, or your own [RdfDriver](https://github.com/flack/createphp/tree/master/src/Midgard/CreatePHP/Metadata)

The whole process is working fine in the symfony2 [CreateBundle](https://github.com/symfony-cmf/CreateBundle/).